# gpg change homedir required typing message?

Tags: gnupg

i tried to change homedir of gpg using the following command:

```
+ gpg --homedir /etc/portage/gnupg
```

the results are:

> gpg: Go ahead and type your message ..

i typed something and pressed ctrl+d, nothing happened.
pressed again, this is the result:

> gpg: processing message failed: Unknown system error

check if the homedir was changed using the command

```
gpg --version
```

but no.

> Home: ~/.gnupg

what did i do wrong?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Import at the same commnad line and it works.

For example,

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net
--recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```

Change this to...

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3
```